# Emitting unknown number of args to pyqtSignal

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, signals

I want to emit unknown number of argument to a pyqtSignal

E.g. when passing unknown args to a def:-

```
def oPrint(*args):
    print(args)
```

I want to do the same with pyqtSignal. Ie:-

```
class UI(QMainWindow):
    msgSig = pyqtSignal(*object) #this gives error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL; DR; Qt needs to know the number of arguments so your requirement cannot be fulfilled.

---

A workaround is to use some container as a list or tuple.

```
class UI(QMainWindow):
    msgSig = pyqtSignal(list)
```

```
ui = Ui()
l = [1, "2", 3, "4"]
ui.msgSig.emit(l)
```

```
def oPrint(args):
    print(args)
```

Comment: I already know this. this works, but it is just a workaround

Comment: @ibrahem I think that with my edition I provide a clearer answer: What you ask is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to emit a tuple/list,
but the receiver can have any number of arguments!

By writing something like this:

```
class UI(QMainWindow):
    msg_sig = Signal(Any)

    def __init__(self):
        self.msg_sig.connect(lambda r: self.out(*r), Qt.QueuedConnection)

    def xx(self):
        self.msg_sig.emit([1, 2, 3])

    def out(args1, args2, args3):
        print(args1, args2, args3)
```

To make it better, you can write your own emit function, take a signal and any number of args, then emit all args as one list.

```
def connect(signal, proc):
    signal.connect(lambda r: proc(*r), Qt.QueuedConnection)


def emit(signal, *args):
    signal.emit(args)
```